# Cannot deserialize instance of boolean from VALUE_STRING value f or request may be missing a required field

Tags: amazon-web-services, boolean, salesforce, amazon-redshift, amazon-appflow

I'm trying to update a Salesforce object using AWS AppFlow. My current process looks like this

AWS REDSHIFT --> S3 <--AppFlow --> Salesforcce

Redshift query is very basic:

```
UNLOAD(
'select 
    contact_id,
    999 contact_score,
    True contact_is_genius
from 
    salesforce.some_table')
TO XXX
FORMAT CSV
IAM_ROLE XXX
HEADER
DELIMITER
CLEANPATH;
```

**However, I'm getting this error which I can't resolve. Any help will be greatly appreciated**

Error: [{"message":"Cannot deserialize instance of boolean from VALUE_STRING value f or request may be missing a required field at [line:1, column:22]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}] Please refer the configured error bucket for more details.

Comment: Can you provide the DDL of salesforce.some_table?  Also, what is reported in "the configured error bucket"?

Comment: The field is a checkbox in Salesforce. Schema of the same table shows it's a BOOL.


Error is as follow (just looking at one record at a time);

{"writeType":"INLINE","errorDetails":[{"error":"[{\"message\":\"Cannot deserialize instance of boolean from VALUE_STRING value t or request may be missing a required field at [line:1, column:22]\",\"errorCode\":\"JSON_PARSER_ERROR\"}]","record":"{\"Contact_Score__c\":\"111\",\"Contact_is_genius__c\":\"t\",\"Id\":\"00Q6700000yJvZ2EAK\"}"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Changed the following line:

''true''::varchar contact_is_genuis